# How to make fragment showing from top toolbar to bottom

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, material-design, bottom-sheet

Hi all I need to make fragment like Bottom down sheet fragment but showing from top to bottom. I know google has class like bottom down sheet but I don't want make the animate showing from bottom to top. How to make bottom down sheet showing from top to bottom.

[image: likethis]

I need to make the fragment showing like line app at chatting activity. Any idea for this ?

Thank you

Comment: take framelayout,below take chat layout above take fragment,when you press toolbar menu ,make fragment visible,if you want animation for top to bottom see expand animation

Comment: So, I cannot use bottom down sheet to implement that case ?

Comment: yes,you can simply create a fragment

Answer (score -1):

DialogPlus can help

> https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus

**Gradle**:

```
implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
```

[image: DialogPlus demo]